# Modify a value in xml file with namespaces using python and lxml

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

Xml file:exercise.xml

```
<Configuration xmlns="http://totem.local/Pane/Configuration">
    <Types>         
        <Type name="F14_simpleGET" clazz="local.totem.zorg.priv.proc.F14.F14_simpleGET" ttl="3600" type="SYNC">
            <Param name="active_installation" value="true"/>
            <Param name="mode_beta" value="false"/>
        </Type>

        <Type name="F15_FixGET" clazz="local.totem.zorg.priv.proc.F15.F15_fixGET" ttl="3600" type="ASYNC">
            <Param name="context" value="Real"/>
            <Param name="Active" value="2"/>
            <Param name="Mode_gama" value="true"/>
        </Type>

    </Types>
    
</Configuration>
```

It's asked to change:

```
<Param name="mode_beta" value="false"/> to <Param name="mode_beta" value="true"/> 
<Param name="Mode_gama" value="true"/> to <Param name="Mode_gama" value="false"/>
```

With a small python script that uses lxml and save the result to result.xml

Please How to do this, Ive tried many things but nothing works

Here something I've tried

```
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('exercise.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for val in tree.xpath("/Configuration/Types/Type[@name='F14_simpleGET']/Param[@name='mode_beta']"):
   val.attrib['value'] = 'true'


  
tree.write('result.xml')
```

Comment: Hello, Zabor. What have you tried so far?

Comment: it's a trainning exercise

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Zabor. It would be best if you added this comment(the code you have mentioned in your comment) to your question in a code block. In this case, we can answer your question more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Kiani, I ve added somthing I ve tried,

Comment: Do you want to do this just using `lxml` or you don't have any boundaries for using any other module?

Comment: Hello Kiani Thank you

the exercise recommends using lxml but I'm open to any other method

Comment: Hello Kiani , its works thanks
can any one helps for doing this by lxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with your original attempt. You just needed to account for the default namespace. (It seems from your question and tagging that you already figured that out though.)

There are a couple of different ways to account for namespaces in lxml ([see the docs](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces)).

My preferred way is to bind the namespace uri to a prefix and use the prefix in the xpath ([see the docs](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes)).

Example (I made up the `tpc` prefix (based on Totem Pane Configuration from the uri); it could be shorter/longer/different)...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("exercise.xml")

ns = {"tpc": "http://totem.local/Pane/Configuration"}

for param in tree.xpath("/tpc:Configuration/tpc:Types/tpc:Type[@name='F14_simpleGET']/tpc:Param[@name='mode_beta']",
                        namespaces=ns):
    param.attrib['value'] = 'true'

for param in tree.xpath("/tpc:Configuration/tpc:Types/tpc:Type[@name='F15_FixGET']/tpc:Param[@name='Mode_gama']",
                        namespaces=ns):
    param.attrib['value'] = 'false'

tree.write("result.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to any other method, I suggest you use `re` (regex) module in order to make change in your XML file:

```py
import re
myXML = """
<Configuration xmlns="http://totem.local/Pane/Configuration">
    <Types>         
        <Type name="F14_simpleGET" clazz="local.totem.zorg.priv.proc.F14.F14_simpleGET ttl="3600" type="SYNC">
            <Param name="active_installation" value="true"/>
            <Param name="mode_beta" value="false"/>
        </Type>

        <Type name="F15_FixGET" clazz="local.totem.zorg.priv.proc.F15.F15_fixGET" ttl="3600" type="ASYNC">
            <Param name="context" value="Real"/>
            <Param name="Active" value="2"/>
            <Param name="Mode_gama" value="true"/>
        </Type>

    </Types>
    
</Configuration>
"""
modifiedXML = re.sub(r'\<Param name="mode_beta" value="false"\/>', '<Param name="mode_beta" value="true"/>' , myXML)
modifiedXML = re.sub(r'\<Param name="Mode_gama" value="true"\/>', '<Param name="Mode_gama" value="false"/>' , modifiedXML)
print(modifiedXML)
```

Note that it won't matter whether you're reading the file from a URL link, a file or even a string, the result would be the same for all:

```
<Configuration xmlns="http://totem.local/Pane/Configuration">
    <Types>         
        <Type name="F14_simpleGET" clazz="local.totem.zorg.priv.proc.F14.F14_simpleGET ttl="3600" type="SYNC">
            <Param name="active_installation" value="true"/>
            <Param name="mode_beta" value="true"/>
        </Type>

        <Type name="F15_FixGET" clazz="local.totem.zorg.priv.proc.F15.F15_fixGET" ttl="3600" type="ASYNC">
            <Param name="context" value="Real"/>
            <Param name="Active" value="2"/>
            <Param name="Mode_gama" value="false"/>
        </Type>

    </Types>
    
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I don't think you'd need the `re` module since you're not doing any regex subs. You _could_ just use the .replace() method on the string. Example of one of the replacements: `myXML.replace(r'<Param name="mode_beta" value="false"/>', r'<Param name="mode_beta" value="true"/>')`. However, this doesn't take into account the context that these `Param` elements are in. The OP is doing additional checks in their xpath statements that are probably important.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks for your comment. I agree entirely with the first part of your comment. Since I haven't used any pattern, the OP could just use `string.replace`. But I think what OP asked is straightforward and does not require additional checking. It would be just replacing one predefined string with another. Even though his/her XPath query is selecting just one of the mentioned `Param`'s, I believe it can be done without using `xtree` module.